# Config nginx for react route

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have problems when refresh pages in my react project, for that I'm trying to configure my Nginx, because in my localhost works ok.

I'm new in Nginx and I've tried for more than 2 hours without success.

**Context:**

1. I have 2 projects in React with React route, then I need to configure for both but I'm trying first configure one.
2. My first project is in `/var/www/html/app` and my second project `/var/www/html/dashboard`, both works well, with `http://MY_IP/app` and `http://MY_IP/dashboard`
3. I opened the the file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`(I removed a lot of commets):

```js
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian-html;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

And only I changed:

- `try_files $uri $uri/ =404; -> try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;`
- `root /var/www/html; -> root /var/www/html/app;`

and After in console: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

**Problem:**

When I made that changes, nothing happens and the page `http://MY_IP/app` is blank.

I tried many variants, but when I refresh `http://MY_IP/app/sale` continue with error and route doesn't work.

what I am doing wrong?, That is the correct file to modify?, any suggestion will be amazing.

**Note:**

- My nginx is in EC2(aws)

Thanks.

Comment: It is correct file to modify.
Check syntax with nginx -t. And restart with nginx -s reload.

Comment: `nginx` URIs have a leading `/`, try: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

Comment: Also, why did you change the value of `root`, when the original value was working?